# Method onReceivedClientCertRequest in Android WebViewClient is called only once

Tags: android, ssl, android-webview, client-certificates

I am trying a two-way mTls authentication on Android using WebView. I installed my client certificate in the Android Keychain and I overrode the method onReceivedClientCertRequest as below to obtain the client cert from the Android Keychain:

```
@Override
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void onReceivedClientCertRequest(WebView view, ClientCertRequest request) {
    Log.d("MC-999","onReceivedClientCertRequest");
    Log.d("MC-999", request.getHost());
    Log.d("MC-999", request.getPrincipals()[0].getName());
    ((WebViewActivity) mContext).selectClientCert(request);
}


@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void selectClientCert(ClientCertRequest request) {
    Log.d("MC-999","Select client cert.");
    mRequest = request;
    KeyChain.choosePrivateKeyAlias(this,
        this, // Callback
        request.getKeyTypes(), 
        request.getPrincipals(), // issuers.
        request.getHost(), // host
        request.getPort(), // port
        "");
}

@Override
@RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public void alias(@Nullable String alias) {
    if (alias != null) {
        X509Certificate[] certChain = getCertificateChain(alias);
        PrivateKey privateKey = getPrivateKey(alias);
        mRequest.proceed(privateKey, certChain);
    } else {
        mRequest.ignore();
    }
}
```

**Issue:**
The method onReceivedClientCertRequest is called only once, the first time. It is not called thereafter. I have to reboot the device to ensure that the client cert is requested again. The documentation also states that

"*Webview stores the response in memory (for the life of the application) if ClientCertRequest#proceed or ClientCertRequest#cancel is called and does not call onReceivedClientCertRequest() again for the same host and port pair.*"

My problem is that if the user chooses the wrong cert the first time, the WebView continuous to use it thereafter. The method ***mWebView.clearSslPreferences();*** doesn't seem to clear the sslContext.

Is there a way to forget the user's certificate choice in case I encounter an SSL error?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `WebView.clearClientCertPreferences` method. It's static method. I faced the same problem as you and this method works fine for me!